# What steps can help burning an iMovie '09 project to DVD when the program crashes?

Tags: imovie, idvd

I have been working on an iMovie multimedia (picture, music, titles, etc.) project for six months using iMovie '09. Six months later it is not allowing me to further add anything to the project, and iMovie keeps crashing on me. I decided to stop, and burn it to iDVD. I have now tried at least 3 times to export project to iDVD to burn this disk, and after two hours of supposed copying; I come back to my computer to find out iMovie `"Quit Unexpectedly"`! The project is approximately 200MB. I just deleted the iDVD preferences playlist, and did verfy and repair disk permissions in Disk Utility.  Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Do you have a backup of the project file from before the time when changes to it have made the program crash?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking out **Software Update** to make sure that there are not any current updated for iMovie '09. I would then just try to export the project in a resolution of your choice to the desktop (or wherever you prefer), and just use **Disk Utility** to burn it from there. This will make sure that you at least have a hard backup of the project, and this may be more effective as you're not trying to run two programs at once (as iMovie is transferring to iDVD). This is key as your system may not have enough RAM to do two high-end processes at once (I don't know your system, so this is only an assumption). This being said, I would try to make sure that you have the fewest amount of programs running during this time period I would then try to take the exported project from the desktop, and throw it into iDVD to burn it with the menus of your liking. I hope this helps, and let me know if you have any more questions.

**Note**: If you are on a laptop make sure it's plugged in, and that you are running a program like [Caffeine](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/caffeine/id411246225?mt=12) to keep it from falling asleep during this process.

Comment: These are good steps if the crash has been fixed in a newer version sadly, the crash can also be a result of a corrupt project and restoring that from a backup or re- cutting the project from the footage often is the practical solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This trick worked on older iMovie versions. I don't know if that's still the case for iMovie'09 and I don't have it at my desk.
You could try to browse your iMovie project from the Finder, delete all the rendered files (transitions, titles, filters). Your project file size may shrink. If it didn't break everything, iMovie will recalculate the render clips. Maybe the disc burning process is failing to process and burn one of those clips.

1 - Quit iMovie since my workaround is done in the Finder.

2 - Very important : duplicate your project file (right-click in the Finder) so you'll have a backup copy if something ever goes wrong.

3 - Right-click on your project file (located in the Movies folder in your Home folder) and select "Show packaged contents"

4 - Look for any Render folders inside the project, and delete every file inside this folder.

5 - Close the Finder window and double-click on your modified project to launch iMovie